# Why is my .net 6 API always returning an empty 200 OK response, even when I use URLs that don't have controllers?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have an API written in .net 6. Program.cs is pretty straightforward, it looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddEventLog(eventLogSettings => { eventLogSettings.SourceName = "My API Auth"; });

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My.API.Auth", Version = "v1" });
    c.OperationFilter<SwaggerDatabaseHeader>();
});

var configSettings = new ConfigSettingsRepository();

if (configSettings.GetAccessTokenExpirationMinutes() * 2 > configSettings.GetRefreshTokenExpirationMinutes())
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("RefreshTokenExpirationMinutes must be more than twice as long as AccessTokenExpirationMinutes");
}

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigSettingsRepository>(configSettings);
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDatabaseProvider, DatabaseProvider>();
builder.Services.RegisterAuthServices(configSettings);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseDatabaseProviderMiddleware();
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Within, there is a simple controller that allows me to ping the api. It looks like this:

```
    [ApiController]
    public class PingController : ControllerBase
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/api/ping")]
        public IActionResult Ping() => Ok(true);
    }
```

The API starts up OK as far as I can tell. But whenever I use my browser to test the ping (http://localhost/myapi/api/ping), I get a 200 response that is blank.

I'm expecting to receive a "true" in that response.
Just as a way to try out that the configuration of the controllers is working or not working in an expected way I used a url like http://localhost/myapi/api/pingdddd - Just a bogus url.

To my surprise this url ALSO returns a 200 blank response.

What the heck is going on?

I tried messing around with IIS URL Rewrite rules. I was able to successfully take URLs that look like "ping" and block them. So I know I'm hitting the right web service, the one I'm expecting.

I've added logging into my code to make sure it is hitting the various parts of my program.cs.  The logging I added was a simple StreamWriter, logging to C:\temp a text file.

By doing this I was able to determine that it is never getting into the body of my ping controller method.

So valid urls, invalid urls, urls with parameters, urls without parameters. Everything returns blank 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. At the beginning of my Program.cs, I was doing this:

```
builder.Logging.AddEventLog(eventLogSettings => { eventLogSettings.SourceName = "My API Auth"; });
```

And in the event viewer, I was getting an error like this:

> The description for Event ID 0 from source Application cannot be
> found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
> your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
> or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
> had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Unable to log .NET application events. The source was not found, but
> some or all event logs could not be searched. To create the source,
> you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new
> source name is unique. Inaccessible logs: Security.
>
> the message resource is present but the message is not found in the
> string/message table

Removing the builder.Logging.AddEventLog line got rid of the event viewer error, and also the api started working exactly as I expected. Ping controller was returning "true" and bogus Urls stopped returning 200 OK.